# Print command output in separate lines

Tags: shell, awk, grep

```
ip a | egrep '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|enp0s' | grep -e 10 -e 172 -e 192 | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{gsub("/24", "");print}' | xargs
```

The above command gives the output as:

```
enp0s3: 10.0.2.15 enp0s8: 192.168.56.100
```

I want the output to be printed in 2 different lines starting with Network card names.

How can I edit the output to get the desired result??

Comment: Then remove `| xargs` in end

Comment: enp0s3:
10.0.2.15
enp0s8:
192.168.56.100

If I remove xargs, I get 4 lines. I want output as Network Card: IP address in 2 different lines

Comment: What is the output of `ip a`? (I'm not on a Linux system).

Comment: change `|xargs` to `|paste - -`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is

```
 ip a | awk '/inet .*enp[0-9]*s[0-9]*/ { print $NF " " gensub(/\/[0-9]*/,"",1,$2); }'
```

Note that I modified the match for the interface name to accept more than enp0s (On my system many of my interfaces are enp2s*). Also, I'm matching lines with 'inet ', this will exclude ipv6 addresses ( 'inet6 ' ).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to give `xargs` a `-L 2` option. 
It would be better simply to do it all in `awk`; it’s very powerful.

You realize that the `-e 10` search string given to `grep`
could easily match an Ethernet address or an IPv6 address.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It would be great if you can show by using awk as well.